# Online polynomial curve fitting in Simulink

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting, simulink

**How to fit curves in Simulink and still generate the code?**

I have a model of a sensor in Simulink, that returns vectors Pos_x and Pos_y. Each vector has size of 20x1, and their values change every one step time (1ms).
I am trying to calculate the coeffecients of the 3rd degree Polynomial `y(x) = p1*x^3 + p2*x^2 + p3*x + p4` in Simulink, that fits the data.

I did not find any block in simulink that calculates the coeffecients, so I used a simple Matlab function

```
function [p1, p2, p3, p4] = fcn(x,y)
    %  f(x) = p1*x^3 + p2*x^2 + p3*x + p4
    f = fit(x', y', 'Poly3');     % I have also tried "polyfit"
    p1 = f.p1;
    p2 = f.p2;
    p3 = f.p3;
    p4 = f.p4;
end
```

but I get the error:
`Function 'fit' not supported for code generation.`

1- so back to my qustion, How to fit curves in Simulink and still generate the code?
2- I am also open to any other suggestion

Answer (score 0):

If possible, you can use directly the LSQCURVEFIT function using Levenberg-Marquardt - method, which is Coder-compatible, with some limitations - see it's documentation that describes the limitations in detail.

Under the hood FIT uses LSQCURVEFIT, but in a non-Coder-compatible way.